# Very thin line between Collection View Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, collections, view, cell

I am seeing a very thin white line in between my collection view cells, even though I have set section insets to 0 and defined the collection view cell to be `self.view.bounds.size.width/2` (there should be two cells per row next to each other).

[image]

(You may have to open the image in full-view to see the white line highlighted in blue).

This is visible on a physical iPhone X device.

Comment: What is `minimumInteritemSpacing`?

Comment: @Ryan the `minimumInteritemSpacing` is `0`

Comment: Does this line visible only in iPhone X?

Comment: @Ryan I also tested on an iPhone 8 and it's visible.

Comment: If `minimumInteritemSpacing == 0`, I assume that the line is from cell. Can you show your code how to configure cell layout and collection layout?

Comment: try it Objective-C: `minimumInteritemSpacing = CGFLOAT_MIN;` swift: `minimumInteritemSpacing =CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude`

Comment: I am experiencing a similar behaviour on iPhone 5s when presenting 3 cells per row. A very thin line appears between the second and third cell. When presenting 2, 4, 5, 6 cell per row everything is fine. It could be some rounding issue, but I still haven't found a way to fix it.

Comment: What kind of layout does this collection view use?

Comment: @AccDa were you ever able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix that by setting minimumInteritemSpacing to -2 and adding +1 to the cell width. Don't know if it's cover all edge cases but it's working for my issue. Hope that this will help someone else